# Remove "Google" appearing on Gboard spacebar

Tags: keyboard, google, gboard

Very recently Gboard updated adding an ugly and distracting "Google" on top of the spacebar. How do I disable this?

Comment: related https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/f9fe8j/new_gboard_now_hasgoogleon_the_space_bar/ https://www.reddit.com/r/gboard/comments/f9ozb7/why_did_google_brand_their_spacebar_with_this/

Answer (score 0):

I saw this [Android Authority tweet](https://twitter.com/AndroidAuth/status/1248593401345454080?s=20) just now expressing disappointment and disapproval of this move by Google.

> We’ve spotted the changes over here at Android Authority too, and we’re guessing it’s a **server-side update** as some of us haven’t enabled automatic app updates. So **rolling back to an earlier of Gboard likely won’t help you.**

(Emphasis added)

What worked for me is having more than one one Gboard languages  English (US), English (India) and two Indian languages apart from SwiftKey. Probably because of  this ,I don't see "Google" and this is supported by others on the tweet thread.

You can add languages to see if it solves the problem

**[Update](https://www.androidauthority.com/gboard-spacebar-google-branding-1104655/amp/?__twitter_impression=true)**

> It appears either the update described below was a mistake or Google has quickly realized that people hate it because it’s already starting to revert back to the way it used to be.
>
> Users are now reporting that the Google-branded space bar is no longer there and the Google search function has returned.